# assign statement for RTL readability in an interface causes assignments or a buffer in synthesis

Tags: interface, system-verilog, synthesis

We have an interface with modports connectin gmodules that looks something like this:

```
interface test_interface (clk, in1, out1);
    input logic in1;
    output logic out1;
    input logic clk;
    logic mid1;
    logic aliased_signal;

    modport a_to_b (
        input in1,
        input clk,
        output mid1,
        input aliased_signal
    );

    modport b_to_a (
        input clk,
        input mid1,
        output out1,
        output aliased_signal
    );

endinterface : test_interface

module top(clock, inpad, outpad);
    input logic clock;
    input logic inpad;
    output logic outpad;

    test_interface test_if(.clk(clock), .in1(inpad), .out1(outpad));

    a A0(.a2b(test_if));
    b B0(.b2a(test_if));

endmodule

module a ( test_interface.a_to_b a2b);

    always_ff @(posedge a2b.clk) begin
        a2b.mid1 <= a2b.in1 & a2b.aliased_signal;
    end

endmodule

module b (test_interface.b_to_a b2a);

    assign b2a.aliased_signal = b2a.out1;

    always_ff @(posedge b2a.clk) begin
        b2a.out1 <= ~b2a.mid1;
    end

endmodule
```

This is a trivial example, but demonstrates the problem.  In the real design, we have, for example 32-bit outputs and 8 bits of that may go to one place and 8 bits to another, etc.  In the destination, they would like to use names that are more meaningful in the destination module, so are using assignments to create those names in the interface so that the destination code isn't using just part of the bits of an obfuscated bus name in the interface.

While the above simulates fine, the result is assignment statements during synthesis (even if using always_comb obviously) and while we can have the synthesis tool insert buffers to make APR happy, this is not desired when these signals are just used as convenient aliases basically.

Is there an RTL coding style with SV interfaces that would allow such "aliasing" without creating complications downstream in synthesis/APR tools?

Below is a closer example to what I'm trying to do.  The "obfuscated_name" signal is an output of the a module because some modules use the name directly from the interface (this could be cleaned up to only do what the a->b connection is doing), but I get the same errors from IUS and DC if I connect to mid2 a->c instead of using the obfuscated_name signal directly.

```
interface test_interface(clk, in1, out1, out2);
    input logic [7:0] in1;
    output logic [3:0] out1;
    output logic [3:0] out2;
    input logic clk;
    logic [7:0] obfuscated_name;
    logic [3:0] mid1;
    logic [3:0] mid2;

    modport a_mp (
        input clk,
        input in1,
        output obfuscated_name
    );

    modport a_to_b (
        input clk,
        input .mid1(obfuscated_name[3:0]),
        output out1
    );

    modport a_to_c (
        input clk,
        input obfuscated_name,
        output out2
    );

endinterface : test_interface

module a ( test_interface.a_mp a_intf);

    always_ff @(posedge a_intf.clk) begin
        a_intf.obfuscated_name <= ~a_intf.in1;
    end

endmodule

module b (test_interface.a_to_b b_intf);

    always_ff @(posedge b_intf.clk) begin
        b_intf.out1 <= b_intf.mid1;
    end

endmodule


module c (test_interface.a_to_c c_intf);

    always_ff @(posedge c_intf.clk) begin
        c_intf.out2 <= ~c_intf.obfuscated_name[7:4];
    end

endmodule



module top( input logic clock,
            input logic [7:0] inpad,
            output logic [3:0] outpad1,
            output logic [3:0] outpad2 );


    test_interface test_if(.clk(clock), .in1(inpad), .out1(outpad1), .out2(outpad2));

    a A0(.a_intf(test_if));
    b B0(.b_intf(test_if));
    c C0(.c_intf(test_if));

endmodule
```

The error I get from IUS is:

> ncvlog: *E,MODPXE (test_interface.sv,18|18): Unsupported modport
>   expression for port identifier 'mid1'.

and DC gives this error:

> Error:  ./b.sv:1: The construct 'b_intf.mid1 (modport expression without a modport from parent)' is not supported in synthesis. (VER-700)

I'm hoping I'm doing something ignorant here and that this is possible what I'm trying to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a feature in Verilog called a *port expression* `.name_of_port(expression_to_be_connected_to_port)` that most people recognize in a *module instance port list* that they don't realize can also be used in the *module deceleration port list header*. This declares the name of the port, and the expression that gets connected to the port. This way a smaller part select of a larger internal bus can be made into a port.

```
module DUT(input clk, inout .data(bus[7:0]) );
  wire [31:0] bus;
endmodule
module top;
  reg clock;
  wire [7:0] mydata;
  DUT d1(.data(mydata), .clk(clock) );
endmodule
```

In SystemVerilog you can do the same thing with a modport expression.

```
interface test_interface (clk, in1, out1);
    input logic in1;
    output logic out1;
    input logic clk;
    logic mid1;
    logic aliased_signal;

    modport a_to_b (
        input in1,
        input clk,
        output mid1,
        input .aliased_signal(out1) // modport expression
    );

    modport b_to_a (
        input clk,
        input mid1,
        output out1
    );

endinterface : test_interface

module top( input logic clock,
            input logic inpad,
            output logic outpad );


    test_interface test_if(.clk(clock), .in1(inpad), .out1(outpad));

    a A0(.a2b(test_if));
    b B0(.b2a(test_if));

endmodule

module a ( test_interface.a_to_b a2b);

    always_ff @(posedge a2b.clk) begin
        a2b.mid1 <= a2b.in1 & a2b.aliased_signal; // port reference to alias
    end

endmodule

module b (test_interface.b_to_a b2a);

    always_ff @(posedge b2a.clk) begin
        b2a.out1 <= ~b2a.mid1;
    end

endmodule
```

Comment: Sorry, new to the site and was trying to show updated code in a comment.  I updated the original question to include what I'm trying and the errors I get from IUS and DC (VCS seems to be ok with this).

Comment: If I use all the bits of the signal and make mid1 8 bits instead of 4, IUS seems happy with it:  input .mid1(obfuscated_name),   but i get the same error from DC, and ultimately this is about avoiding assigns/buffers in synthesis.

Comment: Oops, I did not connect the interfaces correctly I think.  IUS still doesn't like the modport expression  .mid1(obfuscated_name[7:4])  so the part select doesn't work, but once I hook the interfaces up correctly DC seems to be ok with it!

Comment: Works in ModelSim/Questa